# Canadian helping a friend in the States work on his house

Tags: canadian-citizens

My friend has a house in Florida, which will be damaged by the hurricane passing through that area. As a Canadian, can I go to Florida to help him repair his house (unpaid of course)?

Answer (score 6):

https://de.usembassy.gov/unpaid-work-is-work-make-sure-you-have-the-correct-visa/

> Informal arrangements to work in exchange for lodging or meals are also considered unauthorized employment and are not permitted for tourists.

Temporarily suspending these rules for hurricane repairs would be big, big news and I never heard of any such even after the biggest calamities. Compassion is not in the job description of any immigration officers. They are just enforcing the rules, not making up any on spot. And the current USA administration has a proven xenophobic track record.

I am really trying to find a loophole but even if you were a carpenter or such and your friend would employ you so you could try to enter on a TN status under NAFTA

> Not admissible as ST/Ts are persons intending to do work that is normally done by the construction trades (welders, boiler makers, carpenters, electricians, etc.) even where these trades are specialized to a particular industry (e.g. aircraft, power distributions, etc.)

Source: Can't find the original bulletin from 2002 on a gov site but this text is widely available, for eg http://www.ucalgary.ca/biztechlaw/node/300

Bummer. No TN for you.

Comment: Arguably if the asker was not being paid in room and board he might be ok.

Comment: @JacobHorbulyk yes, he'd have to prove he was staying in hotels and paying for all his own meals, transport, and entertainment for the duration though. Even having his friend buy him lunch or a bottle of water could be considered payment.

Comment: Arguably? What is this here today? One person offers their "thoughts" on what immigration might do, the other literally wants you to argue with immigration. Have you all lost your minds? This how people land in a death spiral of visa refusals and so on. No thoughts. No arguments. Laws and regulations and nothing else. Please. Note I went through the Canadian immigration and citizenship process using these principles. It worked.

Comment: The method of payment (or apparent lack thereof, since that can be obscure) is kind of beside the point, it is the nature of the work itself and the fact that other people can be paid to do that kind of work. Even the (foreign) homeowner would be better off not mentioning she is traveling to work on the house; for all they know her job is buying, renovating and flipping houses. And if the homeowner can get into difficulty for that I'm pretty sure her friend can too no matter who buys lunch.

Answer (score -1):

Normally, any work that you do that could displace an American who could be paid to do that labor would be forbidden. So in normal circumstances, you couldn't do any type of construction work.

However, if you tell the border agent that you're coming to do volunteer cleanup work and staying at your friend's home, given the circumstances I don't think you would have a problem. However, this is really only valid for the next few weeks.

Comment: This interpretation of "displace an American who could be paid" seems to me awfully wide. Can I get in trouble for tidying up my hotel bed? Or, when visiting friends, watching over their kids for an evening?

Comment: Tidying the hotel bed, no, the hotel will employs housekeeper regardless. But babysitting can land you in hot water: http://www.cleveland.com/travel/index.ssf/2015/08/babysitter_versus_the_border_p.html